# Is there a name to the "things to handle" design pattern?

Tags: python, algorithm, design-patterns

There's a design pattern I use once in a while, and I don't know what's it called. Perhaps it has a name and someone here knows it?

It's something I use when I want to traverse a tree-like structure and do some action on all of its nodes. It goes something like this:

```
nodes_to_handle = [root_node]
while nodes_to_handle:
    node = nodes_to_handle.pop()
    # handle node
    nodes_to_handle += node.get_neighbors()
```

Note that the structure doesn't have to be a tree; for example, this pattern can be used to do a flood-fill in an array.

So, is there an accepted name to this design pattern?

Comment: breadth-first search

Comment: How is that "breadth-first"? Did you look at the code?

Comment: right, it's `nodes_to_handle.pop()` not `nodes_to_handle.pop(0)`, which means `nodes_to_handle` is a stack, not a queue, and therefore its depth-first.

Comment: Regardless of whether the traversal is done depth-first or breadth-first, what makes this unique is the way I have a list of `nodes_to_handle` that I `.pop` nodes of until it's empty. Isn't there a name for that?

Comment: @coll-RR: Yeah... that's called a stack. Sorry to be a downer, but it's not that unique. Fairly elegant, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're getting at is a more general pattern than depth-first traversal: the frontier list. A frontier list is a (sorted or unsorted) list of elements that still require processing; the algorithm continues removing elements and processing them until the list is empty or some other termination criteria is met.

My favorite example of this pattern is dijkstra's algorithm. In Dijkstra's, the frontier list is a priority queue or heap, and the smallest-valued element is popped off the heap each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the **depth-first traversal** algorithm. (since you pop the list from the end)

It can be implemented generically in a few different ways:

- Using an iterator which traverses the tree (the preferred way)
- Using a traversal function (like yours) with a callback (for the `#handle node` code).

  - Outside the node class
  - Inside the node class
- ...

*Edit: Didn't look at the code properly. :)*

Comment: Sorry.. depth-first it is.. I assumed the two comments where correct, and didn't look too closely at the code.

Comment: Regardless of whether the traversal is done depth-first or breadth-first, what makes this unique is the way I have a list of `nodes_to_handle` that I `.pop` nodes of until it's empty. Isn't there a name for that?

Comment: @cool-RR: Not really. That's just iteration by consuming the list. The more specific thing here (that we focus on) is that you add the node's neighbours' to the list as you go.

Comment: @cool-RR: Also, for flood fill, you'd normally do a breadth-first traversal in all the nodes. (But you need to remember which nodes you've visited since the neighbour graph will have cycles in iot.) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill for flood fill algorithm info.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [depth-first graph traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). It is an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm), not a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29). (From Jochen Ritzel's comment.)